# jqGrid Add Row Data Nested Object

Tags: json, jqgrid

I have a column model like that:

```
...
{name:'password',index:'password', width:100},
{name:'type.name',index:'type.name', width:100},
...
```

My class like definitons:

```
var MyObject = function (password, type) {
    this.password = password;
    this.type = type;
};

var MyType = function (tname) {
    this.tname = tname;
};
```

I populate my variables: like that:

```
var type = new MyType($('#typeList').val());
var myObject = new MyObject($('#password').val(), type);
```

I have a JSON data response from my server and some of it's elements are object as like type. When I want to show them at my grid its OK. However when I want to use addrowdata function I can not see anything at `type` column. I am doing like that:

```
$("#gridId").jqGrid('addRowData', myObject.password, myObject, "first");
```

class is the function that hold name, password etc. inside it. The problem is only with nested elements(I can see password etc. at my grid). `addrowData` fonction accepts an array but I send a abject that holds object. How can I convert my object of objects into a plaint object array?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use points in the `name` property! If needed you can use if in `index` or in `jsonmap`.

The usage of [addRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) in your example seems me wrong. You should reread the documentation of [addRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method.

Comment: name is a field at my server side and it is the id element of my object so thats why I use class.name as rowid. (I am getting the JSON marshalled version from server)

Comment: @kamaci: You should include in the text of your question the definition of jqGrid which you use. Additionally the test JSON data which you receive from the server can explain many things. Currently you wrote: "I can not see anything at `type` column" and posted no definition of `type` column. instead of that use posted `{name:'type.name',index:'type.name', width:100}` which is definitively wrong because the value of `name` property ('type.name' in you case) not allowed to have points inside. You can try with `{name:'name', index:'type.name', jsonmap:'type.name', width:100}`.

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried to be more clear and explained more my situation. I have updated my question.

Comment: @kamaci: I still not understand what you need. I don't understand why you use `addRowData` method which is slow. Moreover if you do need to add a row of data and need use `addRowData` why you don't create temporary simple "flat" object from the "nested" object and use the "flat" object as the parameter of `addRowData`? The code will be simple and clear. In any way you should not use `name` property which has points inside.

Comment: thanks for your comment and opinions. Data comes from server side and has a field: `name`. If server adds new data into database I add row data into grid instead of reloading grid from server side. Is there any alternative to `addRowData`?

Comment: I will try to use a `flat` object as you suggested

Comment: @kamaci: It's not important which fields has JSON data which come from the server. You can choose any value for 'name' property of the columns independent from the fields in JSON. What you should do is define 'jsonmap' property like I described before. For example `{name:'name', index:'type.name', jsonmap:'type.name', width:100}`. To say you any advice about alternative to `addRowData` I need have much more information about jqGrid which you use and the JSON format  from the server response. Currently you just wrote "I want to use addrowdata function" without any explanation.

Comment: Do you mean something like that: `{name:'typeName',index:'type.name', jsonmap:'type.name', width:100}` when you say do not point inside?

Comment: I didn't use `type.name` at `name` field. I did what I wrote my previous comment. I hope I understand what you mean. Also I used a flattened object and it works. Thanks for your help.